# Joomla javascript var with HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, var

I'm trying to implement a Javascript Tooltip component in a Joomla template. The tooltip shows a bit of text everytime you do roll-over on some images.

The problem is what follows. I'm storing the text for each tooltip in an array, like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function()
{

var bubbles = new Array();

bubbles[0] = "<div class='bubbleTooltip'><p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p><p>What's your favourite food?</p><p>- Chocolate</p></div>"

bubbles[1] = "<div class='bubbleTooltip'><p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p><p>What's your favourite food?</p><p>- Chocolate</p></div>"

bubbles[2] = "<div class='bubbleTooltip'><p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p><p>What's your favourite food?</p><p>- Chocolate</p></div>"

});

</script>
```

But when I look at the page source code, it looks like so:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function()
    {

    var bubbles = new Array();

    bubbles[0] = "
<div class='bubbleTooltip'>
<p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p>
<p>What's your favourite food?</p>
<p>- Chocolate</p>
</div>
"

    bubbles[1] = "
<div class='bubbleTooltip'>
<p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p>
<p>What's your favourite food?</p>
<p>- Chocolate</p>
</div>
"

    bubbles[2] = "
<div class='bubbleTooltip'>
<p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p>
<p>What's your favourite food?</p>
<p>- Chocolate</p>
</div>
"

    });

    </script>
```

What makes the complement don't work. I think that it might have something to do with the HTML tags, but I can't seem to find the clue...

Any ideas about why is the code rendering wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by complement don't work? is it only code rendering or are you not able to access the array elements?

Comment: The thing is that if I replace the HTML Strings for normal Strings, everything works fine. The problem appears when I use HTML Strings and the code renders wrong. Then I'm not able to access the array elements due to the code bad formating.

Comment: are you using the joomla text editor for adding your code? It is possible that Joomla is escaping your html characters

Comment: Yes I'm. Is there any other way to edit the code? I've tried searching the file in the ftp, but its all a mess of folders... I'm not the regular administrator of the site.

Comment: If you are using text editor for TinyMCE there is settings that you can turn off to not escape the html, try this 
Code cleanup on startup off
Code cleanup: Always
Do Not Clean HTML entities No

if your using some other text editor search for corresponding settings, i need to check where you can locate js as i have not used joomla for long time

Comment: The editor is set to JCE and all the Text Filters are in No filter. Do you think this could be having anything to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43470/discussion-between-raunak-kathuria-and-albert-espinosa-aguado)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Joomla editors escape the html characters, you need to turn off the settings for this.

- Code cleanup on startup off
- Code cleanup: Always
- Do Not Clean HTML entities

For general setting Check this link http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/item/html-removed-on-saving

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try assigning html string to array elements in following way

```
bubbles[0] = "<div class='bubbleTooltip'>"+
"<p>iPhone or BlackBerry?</p>"+
"<p>What's your favourite food?</p>"+
"<p>- Chocolate</p>"+
"</div>";
```

Comment: I think it will still escape the html elements because of default configuration